# What languages compile to the most efficient Javascript code? (besides C & C++)

Tags: javascript, asm.js

There are lots of [languages that compile to javascript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) these days, with C & C++ compiled to asm.js being touted as the fastest. I was wondering what other candidates exist for efficient, compiled Javascript/asm.js. I'd to find a nice language that strikes a balance between performance and having modern, higher-level programming constructs. Everyone seems to love Python these days but from what I've read it doesn't make for the fastest compiled JS.

Based on some initial perusing of the topic, I'm getting the idea that Dart, Haxe, C# and Java may be good candidates but I haven't been able to find any performance comparisons.

Comment: It really depends upon the type of code being compile. e.g. the loop in a strcpy goes *really well* to ASM.js; However, what happens when a rich notion of protocols and dynamic typing is added? Well, that *has* to be accounted for, e.g. with a "slow Python VM" (or restricted as in RPython). So is a [C-based] Python VM compiled for ASM.js better than such a VM compiled native? Therein lies the crux of why some languages are good/practical for such compilation targets, and some are not.

Comment: Before performance comparison can be made, it (compilation to JS/asm.js) has to *work* in the first place. Dart and HaXe have JS backends, but I don't think there are JS compilers for C# or Java (GWT perhaps?). Once asm.js is mature enough, the language that compiles to the fastest asm.js code should (in theory) be the one that compiles to the fastest native machine code, modulo architecture-specific optimizations like vectorization.

Comment: This is not really a question appropriate to StackOverflow, but check out ClojureScript too.

Comment: delnan - there are a number of JS compilers for C# and Java. (GWT as you mention compiles Java to JS.)